# How should I use CTE With clause Syntax on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do the same thing in here which is done using Microsoft SQL server:[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOwe.jpg)

But when I do the same in BigQuery I keep getting this Error: *Syntax error: Expected keyword AS but got "(" at [78:14]*

Comment: Edit your question and include the query you are running in BigQuery *as text*.  As a note:  your query does not have 78 lines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#simple_cte) where it explains how is the query syntax. You are missing the "AS" right after "PopvsVac".

For instance:

```
WITH Roster AS
 (SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, 50 as SchoolID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', 51 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', 77)
SELECT * FROM Roster
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the problem is in the first line when using with you cant use ( before as
just remove the () and the data in them and the query should work